# Inflating fragment from an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wanna inflate some fragment from an activity (which is not main but is activity).

I do exactly like this instruction:

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

  YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
  fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);//here is the error
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

but in the one before last line,  editor shows error saying:

---

> 2nd argument wrong type.Found:max.mzf.max.fragment.Required:android.app.fragment

---

this is my own code:

*Activity*

```
public class QuizCard extends FragmentActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz_card);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =      fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    QcardFragment fragment = new QcardFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, fragment  );
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.card_menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

---

and this is QcardFragment:

---

```
public class QcardFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //get data from Argument
}
public void onCardClick(View view) {
    flipCard();
}
private void flipCard() {
    View rootLayout = (View) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_activity_root);
    View cardFace = (View) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_activity_card_face);
    View cardBack = (View) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_activity_card_back);

    FlipAnimation flipAnimation = new FlipAnimation(cardFace, cardBack);

    if (cardFace.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        flipAnimation.reverse();
    }
    rootLayout.startAnimation(flipAnimation);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.qcardfragment, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


}
}
```

---

What's wrong?

Comment: this problem was resolved by @LUCIUS HIPAN's guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that  your fragment class `extends Fragment` from android native library. If you are using external implementation try to change

`FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();`

to

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: I couldnt get anything maybe I'm confused.

Comment: i want to see the imports. What Fragment do you import ?

Comment: do you have this line import android.support.v4.app.Fragment ?

Comment: android.support.v4.app.Fragment is imported

Comment: than you need to use supportFragmentManager as I answered, FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

Comment: required:android.app.FragmentManager  Found::android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Comment: and the before one is also existing

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; and delete import android.app.FragmentManager;